# shell script to convert string to datetime

Tags: shell, unix

I have a string that has a long value of date stored in a variable, for example dt="20190501131050", want to convert that to dat to subtract 15 minutes from that value to become 20190501125550

I tried to cast as date using (date -d) but got error invalid date

```
     dt="20190501131050"
     dt2=$(date -d "$dt" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
dt="20190501131050"
dt=$(echo "$dt" | sed "s/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/15 minutes ago \1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/")
date -d "$dt" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
```

**explanation**

Decomposes date into individual elements, arranges them at a valid date and subtracts 15 minutes.

**output**

```
20190501125550
```